# Deleting adjacent double letters from an array of a string

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I wrote this code to delete certain characters from a string which I convert to an array of characters.

```
function extractChar(str) {
  var array = [];
  array = str.split('');

  for (i=1;i<arguments.length;i++) {
    for (x=0;x<array.length;x++) {
      if (array[x] === arguments[i]) {
        var temp = array.indexOf(array[x]);
        array.splice(temp,1);
      }
    }
  }
  document.write(array);
}

extractChar('hello my name is frank','f','m','l');
```

The code works fine for deleting a character that appears once in the array (the 'f' in this case). It also works for deleting double characters that are not adjacent to each other (the 'm's in this case).

However, it does not work for double letters that are adjacent to each other (the 'l's in this case). Why is this? It does work for two different letters that are next to each other (like the 'f' and 'r'). Why not for double letters?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you splice the array, the next index will decrement by one, so you need to decrement your 'x' accordingly =)

function extractChar(str) {
      var array = [];
      array = str.split('');

```
  for (i=1;i<arguments.length;i++) {
    for (x=0;x<array.length;x++) {
      if (array[x] === arguments[i]) {
        var temp = array.indexOf(array[x]);
        array.splice(temp,1);
        x--;
      }
    }
  }
  document.write(array);
}

extractChar('hello my name is frank','f','m','l');
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To delete adjacent double letters  in JavaScript, do this

```
function deleteDuplicates(string) {
    return string.replace(/(.)\1{1,}/g, '');
}

deleteDuplicates("hello")
=> "heo"
```